# What does $C = 2 \pi r$ means?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

It's a fact that the length of a circunference it's given by the equation $C = 2 \pi r$. But once a circunference it's an infinite set of points, if the radius it's fixed, this is a real function so $C \in \mathbb{R}_+$. I think my doubt it's more related to measurement.

Is $C(r)$ independent of measurement, or independent of a fixed unit?

Can someone give me some reference to study this things, something in geometry, but that goes deeper than calculating areas of polygons?

Comment: Maybe you should look at Archimedes' method for approximating $\pi$.

Comment: What do you mean by independent of measurement?

Answer (score 4):

The symbols $C,r$ in the formula $C=2\pi r$ are real number measurements, each made with respect to a fixed unit.

The real number $r$ represents the length of any line segment connecting the center of the circle to any point on the circle itself. The word "radius" is used ambiguously: sometimes it means one of those line segments, regarded as an infinite set of points; other times it means the common length of those line segments.

The real number $C$ represents the length of the circle itself. The word "circumference" is also used ambiguously: sometimes it means, as you say, the circle itself regarded as an infinite set of points; other times it means the length of the circle.

It is a theorem of Euclidean geometry that for any circle whose radii all have length $r$ (no matter what the center of that circle), its circumference has length $C=2 \pi r$; sometimes that ancient theorem is stated by saying that the ratio $C/r$ is independent of the circle.

Nowadays, the slickest rigorous proof of the formula $C = 2 \pi r$ uses calculus, usually 1st or 2nd semester calculus. There are, however, ancient proofs of the formula $C = 2 \pi r$ which can be made rigorous in the modern sense. See for example [here](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fc-2012-02), where you will see that Archimedes wrote a paper on this topic, and Euclid also gave a proof, each of which is still extant.